# Apex Performance Query

Tags: apex, performance

I have the following scenario occuring in my code:

Custom Object A has 100 records.

Custom Object B also has 100 records (*every record of B will have a corresponding record with A*).

```
for (Custom_Object_A a : A_Collection) {
    for (Custom_Object_B b : B_Collection) {
        if (b.id == a.id) {
            b.field1 = a.field1;
        }
    }
}
update B_Collection;
```

So the above code will execute 100 * 100 = 10000 computations.

Will this be memory intensive on Salesforce ?

Comment: Yes, when you find yourself writing nested loops stop and find a way to avoid it. Some detail here [Fixing a common cause of System.LimitException: Apex CPU time limit exceeded](https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/11/09/fixing-a-common-cause-of-system-limitexception-apex-cpu-time-limit-exceeded/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a map. By the way, two records of different `SObjectType` will never have the same `Id`, because they will have a different key prefix (the first three characters). You can see this for yourself:

```
system.assertNotEquals(SObjectType.A__c.getKeyPrefix(), SObjectType.B__c.getKeyPrefix());
```

I will assume there is some sort of lookup relationship. It does not really matter which direction. I will take your word that the relationship is 1-to-1.

```
Map<Id, A__c> aMap = new Map<Id, A__c>([SELECT Id FROM A__c]);
for (B__c b : [SELECT A__c FROM B__c])
    A__c correspondingRecord = aMap.get(b.A__c);
```

Comment: Hmm...I was doing Map before. also..i just wanted to which one would be less strainful on Salesforce servers..I am gonna keep the processing with the @future notation as such i will have like 60 sec of CPU time when compared to synchronous which is 10 sec...

Comment: Um. So does this answer your question? I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Tx for your response....I did try out the functionality via Map and its working fine. I just wanted to know which among these two ("M x N" vs Map) is less strainful on Salesforce servers ?..Hope I am clear

Comment: It is definitely more efficient to use a map and a single loop. `Apex` generates `Map<Id, SObject>` very efficiently.